# NumberFormatter with singular / plural word

Tags: php, number-formatting, icu

Is it possible to use PHP [`NumberFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php) class to display words in singular or plural depending on the number value using the [`setPattern`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.setpattern.php) method?

This method is using the [`ICU DecimalFormat`](http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classDecimalFormat.html) library, but I am not familiar with it.

I would like to use plural on the `page` word when value is more than 1:

```php
$sizeFormatter = new NumberFormatter('fr_FR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$sizeFormatter->setPattern('#0.# page(s)');
```

Answer (score 0):

DecinalFormat's pattern supports subpattern selection by number sign.
So you can use little hack like `$number > 1  ? $number : -$number` to set singular / plural word with it. Output number will be positive.

```
$sizeFormatter = new NumberFormatter('fr_FR', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL);
$sizeFormatter->setPattern('0 pages; 0 page');

$number = 3;
echo $sizeFormatter->format($number > 1  ? $number : -$number);
```

Comment: Not possible without a hack? I would like to not change the original value.

Comment: С NumberFormatter::DECIMAL, probably not. You can do it via `MessageFormatter` class. [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.messageformatter.php),  [Example with plural using](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/messages)

Comment: @Seb33300 there's no change original value. It just add condition `> 1`. Can you provide details of what you want?